# Beautiful Soup 4's extract() Changing the tag to a NoneType

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the name, price and description of an item from a webpage.

Here is the HTML

```
...
<div id="ProductDesc">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="loadStyle('imageView','http://tendeep.vaesite.net/__data/03cc09aa3700a50b17caf5963821f603.jpg', '',  '',  '')"><h5 id="productTitle">Split Sport Longsleeve T-shirt</h5></a>
                            <h5 id="productPrice">$42.00</h5>
                            <br style="clear:both;" /><br />
                        Style # 53TD4141 Screenprinted longsleeve cotton tee.</div>
...
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
line = soup.find(id="ProductDesc")
name = line.h5.extract()
print name.get_text()
price = line.h5.extract()
print price.get_text()
desc = line.get_text()
print desc
```

It outputs:

```
Split Sport Longsleeve T-shirt
$42.00
```

Then the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/home/myfile.py", line 35, in siftInfo
    print line.get_text()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 901, in get_text
    strip, types=types)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 876, in _all_strings
    for descendant in self.descendants:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1273, in descendants
    current = current.next_element
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_element'
```

I would like the output:

```
Split Sport Longsleeve T-shirt
$42.00
Style # 53TD4141 Screenprinted longsleeve cotton tee.
```

Note:

If I `print line` instead of print `line.get_text()` it returns:

```
Split Sport Longsleeve T-shirt
$42.00
<div id="ProductDesc">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadStyle('imageView','http://tendeep.vaesite.net/__data/03cc09aa3700a50b17caf5963821f603.jpg', '',  '',  '')"></a>

                            <br style="clear:both;"/><br/>
                        Style # 53TD4141 Screenprinted longsleeve cotton tee.</div>
```

Edit 1:

If I omit the two lines concerning price and add some parsing out of white space then I get this:

New Code:

```
line = soup.find(id="ProductDesc")
name = line.h5.extract()
print name.get_text()
desc = line.get_text()
print (' ').join(desc.split())
```

Output:

```
Split Sport Longsleeve T-shirt
$42.00 Style # 53TD4141 Screenprinted longsleeve cotton tee.
```

So, the second `line.h5.extract()` is somehow changing the type of line, but the first one is not.

Comment: I ran your first piece of code 10 times (in Python 3) and couldn't reproduce your error.  Are you sure it was the same page (website.com/store/split-sport-longsleeve-t-shirt)?  Another thing I noticed about the page was that it did use javascript, so when a site uses javascript it is always good to do a `print(soup)` at the beginning to make sure the information you want has loaded.

Comment: Please clarify the scenerio!

Comment: This is the website url: http://10deep.com/store/split-sport-longsleeve-t-shirt

Comment: @dstudeba it definitly has the information that i want since it prints it in the Edit 1.

Comment: @SIslam Which part of the scenario needs clarifcation.

Comment: @dstudeba what output are you getting when you don't get the error?

Comment: url is: http://10deep.com/store/split-sport-longsleeve-t-shirt
Split Sport Longsleeve T-shirt
$42.00




      Style # 53TD4141 Screenprinted longsleeve cotton tee.

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it doesn't format well in the comment I am putting it here.  This is the code I ran and the output I got:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

def mainTest():
    url = "http://10deep.com/store/split-sport-longsleeve-t-shirt"
    print("url is: " + url)
    page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    line = soup.find(id="ProductDesc")
    name = line.h5.extract()
    print(name.get_text())
    price = line.h5.extract()
    print(price.get_text())
    desc = line.get_text()
    print(desc)

mainTest()
```

Output

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/{path}/testPython.py
url is: http://10deep.com/store/split-sport-longsleeve-t-shirt
Split Sport Longsleeve T-shirt
$42.00




                        Style # 53TD4141 Screenprinted longsleeve cotton tee.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you, it must be an issue specific to python 2.7 then. I may just write alot of regex and separate the price from the description using that.